# MediaPlayer not getting initialized (On a single smartphone)

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm making a simple app with some buttons that, when pressed, audio starts.
So far has all worked nice, me & other friends installed the APK and it works fine, but a friend of mine with a Meizu has a problem.

[image]
As seen in this log, im trying to invoke start on a null object (line 139) but

```
playNonAma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override<br>
        public void onClick(View v) {
            universalMP.stop();
            universalMP.release();
            universalMP = null;
            universalMP = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), raw.perche_non_mi_ama);
            universalMP.start();
        }});
```

I'm clearly setting to null the MP and then re-allocating it, in fact it just works fine on other phones, why does he have this bug then?

Comment: i'm not familiar with media players in android but maybe it's some kind of codec problem? are you sure you have the needed codecs on said phone?

Comment: Most of the files are .mp3 and whatsapp audio so i dont thik it should matter...